# Excel VBA code to negate values

Tags: vba, excel

I'm writing a VBA code in Excel to modify the values of a certain column:

- If the cell C(i) is "Debit" the multiply the amount in cell B(i) by -1
- otherwise do nothing!

Below is my code, but sadly it doesn't work :(

```
    Private Sub Calc()
    For Each transType In Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C4", "C100")
    myRow = transType.Row
    oldAmount = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & myRow)
    If transType.Value = "D" Then
    newAmount.Value = oldAmount.Value * -1
    Else:
    newAmount = oldAmount
    End If
    Cells(myRow, "B").Value = newAmount
    Next transType
    End Sub
```

Comment: The things you need to look out to: 1. define variable types. I'm fairly confident your VBE didn't know you considered `transType` to be a `Range`; 2. Don't refer to properties of undefined variables. If a variable is defined the `.` written after the variable's name will enable you to select from a list, if it doesn't appear, you're in the wrong. 3. Remove unnecessary steps, telling the new value equals the old value gives you nothing. Keep up though, you will write awesome subs in no time.

Comment: According to your narrative you want to compare column C to *Debit* but your code compares it to *D*. Should you be using `If Left(transType.Value, 1) = "D" Then` ?

Comment: @Jeeped Sorry for the mixup in my cells I had "D". When I posted here I wrote "Debit" to make it more clear. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Private Sub Calc()
Dim transType As Range, oldAmount as range 'important
For Each transType In Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C4", "C100")
myRow = transType.Row
If transType.Value Like "D*" Then 'if it's "D" something, e.g. "D" or "Deb" or "Debit"
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & myRow).Value = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & myRow).Value * -1
End If
'Cells(myRow, "B").Value = newAmount 'this won't work, it asks for index, the index for column B is 2
Next transType
End Sub
```

Comment: `Cells(myRow, "B").Value = newAmount` this will work exactly the same way as `Cells(myRow, 2).Value = newAmount`

Comment: I have been living a lie. Mi scuzi.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a bit of a mash-up of methods and some steps can probably be removed.

```
Private Sub Calc()
    Dim transType As Range
    With Worksheets("Sheet2")
        For Each transType In .Range("C4").Resize(97, 1)
            If Left(transType.Value, 1) = "D" Then _
                transType.Offset(0, -1) = transType.Offset(0, -1).Value * -1
        Next transType
    End With
End Sub
```

Try to work within a specific workspace. Defining the worksheet with a With/End With clause and prefacing all `.Cell` and `.Range` references with a period will bestow that worksheet as the parent of the cells. Since you are looping through a `For Each`, you need only offset one column to the left to access column B from column C. As mentioned in my comment, I'm unclear on whether you are using *Debit* or *D* as criteria but this will work for either; the `Left` function is simply unnecessary if column C only contains *D*..

Answer (score 0):

Directly using EVALUATE

```
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("D4:D100") = Evaluate("=IF(LEFT(Sheet2!C4:C100,1)=""D"",-1*(Sheet2!D4:D100),Sheet2!D4:D100)")
```